# Using where clause in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel

I have two tables. 'Bids' in which admin will start bid on a product. and another table 'bid_offers' in which the users who want to buy will give their own bids on these products.
on my home page i am passing bids and bid_offers. I am displaying the product from bid. Now I want to count how many bid offers are on each particular product. How would i be able to do that?
[This is the bids table attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMYxZ.png)[This is the bid_offers table attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPwFB.png)
This below is the blade template where I want to apply this where clause to count the Number of bids offered by users for this particular product.

```
    <div class="row auctions-entry">
                        @foreach($bids as $bid)
                        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="item">
                                <div>
                                    <strong class="price">$ {{$bid->bidding_price}}</strong>
                                    <a href="{{route('user_bid')}}"><img src="{{asset('assets/auction_user_files/images/xproduct_1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.jv58llKnOW.webp')}}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="p-4">
                                    <h3><a href="{{route('user_bid')}}">{{$bid->products->name}}</a></h3>
                                    <div class="d-flex mb-2">
                                        <span>{{$bid->products->sub_category->name}}</span>
                                        <span class="ml-auto">count the bids on this product?</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="{{route('user_bid')}}" class="btn btn-bid">Submit a Bid</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
```

This is what i am passing from the controller.

```
    public function show_index()
        {
            $bids = Bid::inRandomOrder()->limit(8)->get();
            $bid_offers = BidOffer::all();
        
            return view('user_views_auction/index', compact('bids', 'bid_offers'));
        }
```

Note: I am using Laravel 5.8.

Comment: Use the laravel way and make Bid HaveMany BidOffer   .. so you can just say $bid->bid_offers->count();   Look up HasMany and (you will need to modify your relationship function because of your naming conventions).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the table schema you provide, your `bid` belongs to an `product` and a `bid` has many `bid_offers`. Same as how you would map from `bid` to `product`, I think the easiest way is defining relationship in both `bid` and `bid_offers` model.

So, in your `App\Models\Bid` model, you can do something like:

```php
public function bid () 
{
  return $this->hasMany(BidOffer::class);
}
```

and in your `App\BidOffer` model, you can do

```php
public function bid_offers ()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Bid::class);
}
```

Remember that since you have custom foreign_key, you will need to [define that](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) as well in your relation.
Now once you have the relation, you can easily count the number of bid_offers on each bid. Simply to

```php
$bid->bid_offers->count();
```

In fact, this way you don't even need to call `$bid_offers = BidOffer::all();` in your controller.

Finally, in your blade, you can use Eloquent to retrieve whatever you want, like you can do:

```php
{{ \App\Models\BidOffer::where('bid_id', $bid->id)->count() }}
```

**This would work but is not the elegant way to do.**